# java how to use value from one method to another method

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring mvc where  I have a **User.java** class,which has name,username and password fields.
from the html page I am fetching the name and username and generating password field..
   I have the code below:---

```
 public Student addStudent(String name, String username, String password) {
            Student student = new Student(name,username,password);
            student.setPassword(GeneratePwd.pw(stylepwd.generate()));
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
            return student;
            }
```

now,I want to pass the  "**addStudent**" methods value to the "**getStudentActivity**" method

```
public void getStudentActivity(Student student) {

        student.getName();
        student.getPassword();
    }
```

but, in **getStudentActivity** methos the `student.getName();` is returning the result but `student.getPassword();` returns **null**..why??

Comment: Is password getting saved properly?

Comment: What happens in GeneratePwd class? Does setter sets the field? Does getter do some 'extra' work?

Comment: @ Naman Gala ,  yes,It is saving to the database properly..

Comment: @lukaslew , GeneratePwd is a class where pw has a method,its only generates the password.

Comment: password is a String field? What happens between these two method? Do you do something like `getStudentActivity(addStudent(...))`?

Comment: There is a missing parameter `,)` in method `public Student addStudent` signature.

Comment: @ gyan ,I have corrected it..

Comment: Whats the reason for down vote???Here,I have seen many people who can not solve the ques they gives down vote..

Comment: @ lukaslew , yes password field is String type..And I have posted the how I am accessing the "addStudent" method..do u have any idea what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Salini Don't get demotivated with downvote, you have asked a genuine question and on this forum we have more good people.

Comment: @Salini But do you do some extra actions between these two methods? Do you debug the code? Does the student instance from `addStudent` is the same as instance in `getStudentActivity`? If you take instance from DB, does password field is set?

Comment: Debugging the code would give you a conclusive answer in 5 minutes, there's not enough information to diagnose your problem currently.

Answer (score -1):

Check, whether this code `student.setPassword(GeneratePwd.pw(stylepwd.generate()));` is working or not.

Just place the code and see the console output/log to see if indeed `GeneratePwd.pw ()` is working and session factory is not doing anything funcky?

```
student.setPassword(GeneratePwd.pw(stylepwd.generate()));
System.out.println(student.getPassword());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);
System.out.println(student.getPassword());
```

Comment: Could you please post, on how you are calling these two methods from the main program?

Comment: reason for down vote : it is not a solution OP is asking for it should be comment.

Comment: @PiyushMittal Problem solving is a systematic approach and you should refrain from DownVoting unless someone is posting a wrong answer. With great power comes the greater responsibility.